# ContourPlot fails with composite condition?

Tags: plotting

In this very simple example I try to  evaluate the contours of `x^2+y^2==1||x^2+y^2==2` (two circles) but Mathematica

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

doesn't evaluate ! `Evaluate` doesn't help.

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123910/discussion-on-question-by-ulrich-neumann-contourplot-fails-with-composite-condit).

Answer (score 1):

This is meant as a comment but I do not know how to add commands to comments.

My idea was to use the `ImplicitRegion` command.

```
test = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2, {x, y}]
RegionPlot[test]
```

The result of the final command is shown below.

[image]

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks for this nice workaround. I'm still hoping to understand why ContourPlot doesn't work with composite condition.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ContourPlot[Boole[x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

? Please, play with color on your own.

Comment: The result of `ColorNegate[
 ContourPlot[
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]` is not very well.

Comment: Tricky idea , thanks. But `ContourPlot[
 Boole[ x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2 || x^2 + y^2 == 3 ], {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2} ]` only shows two circles.  The option  `Contours->{1}` doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Try `ContourPlot[
 Boole[x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2]*
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 == 3 || x^2 + y^2 == 4], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`. In my opinion, `ImplicitRegion` is the right command for such things.